# do implicit transactions not update second level cache?

Tags: java, hibernate

In an post titled "Use of implicit transactions is discouraged" [here](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/hprof/learn/alert/donotuseimplicittransactions), the post states that *"forgoing the use of explicit transactions has the effect of mulling the 2nd level cache.....The reasons is that until we commit a transaction, Hibernate will not update the cache with the values for the loaded entities."*

I cannot find any reference confirming this statement. Perhaps I'm not searching for the correct terms. Is this statement true? Don't implicit transactions still perform a commit, and if so, why would the cache not be updated?